# IllegalStateException for distributed system in Infinispan

Tags: distributed, infinispan

I have been trying to implement a distributed system that would store data in the node that does a get command. My idea was to use the KeyAffinityService to find a key that is associated with the local node and each time a before a put command is done, store a key that would refer to the same local node and use a grouping API that would use this key to store the value in the local node.
The code I have is the following:

**SimpleCache.java:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import org.infinispan.Cache;
import org.infinispan.affinity.*;
import org.infinispan.manager.*;

//Used to store the key for the local node
class locaddr{ static String nut; static String sim;}

public class SimpleCache {
public void start() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedCacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager("democluster.xml");

    Cache<String, String> cache = manager.getCache();
    String command = "";
    int ticketid = 1;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    cache.start();
    manager.start();

    // Create the affinity service to find the Key for the manager
    KeyAffinityService keyAffinityService = KeyAffinityServiceFactory.newLocalKeyAffinityService(
            cache,
            (KeyGenerator)new RndKeyGenerator(),
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
            100);


    //Find key associated with local node
    locaddr.nut = Objects.toString(keyAffinityService.getKeyForAddress(manager.getAddress()));


    log("Start of program.....");
    log("Input one of following commands:");
    log("book");
    log("pay");
    log("list");
    log("locaddr");
    log("quit");
    while (true){
        command = scan.nextLine();
        if (command.equals("book")) {
            log("Enter name ");

            String name = scan.nextLine();

            locaddr.sim = Objects.toString(keyAffinityService.getCollocatedKey(locaddr.nut));
            cache.put(Integer.toString(ticketid)+manager.getAddress().toString(),name);

            log("Booked ticket " + name);
            ticketid++;
        }
        else if (command.equals("pay")) {

            log("Enter ticket number ");
            String id = scan.nextLine();

            log("Display ticket:"+cache.get(id));

            String ticket = cache.remove(id);
            log("Checked out ticket " + ticket);
        }
        else if (command.equals("list")) {
            Set <String> set = cache.keySet();
            for (String ticket: set) {
                log(ticket + " " + cache.get(ticket));
            }
        }
        else if (command.equals("quit")) {
            cache.clear();
            cache.stop();
            manager.stop();
            keyAffinityService.stop();
            log("Bye");
            break;
        }
        else if (command.equals("locaddr")) {
            log("local key for manager is: "+locaddr.nut);
            log("manager address is: " + manager.getAddress());
        }
        else {
            log("Unknown command " + command);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    new SimpleCache().start();
}
public static void log(String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

**democluster.xml:**

```
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 
http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:6.0">

<global>
        <transport>
            <properties>
                <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups-tcp.xml" />
            </properties>
        </transport>
</global>

<default>
    <clustering mode="distributed" >
        <sync/>
        <hash numOwners="1" numSegments="100" capacityFactor="1">
            <groups enabled="true">
                <grouper class="KXGrouper"/>
            </groups>
        </hash>
    </clustering>
</default>
</infinispan>
```

**KXGrouper.java:**

```
import org.infinispan.distribution.group.Grouper;

public class KXGrouper implements Grouper<String> {

public String computeGroup(String key, String group) {
    String g = locaddr.sim;
    return g;
}

public Class<String> getKeyType() {
    return String.class;
}
}
```

My implementation is based in a simple cache implementation example of infinispan. However I am having two main issues:

**1.**
When I run this code in separate JVMs, sometimes it will work but sometimes when I do a "book" command (which invokes the collocated key command and the cache put command), I get an error where it says the another node is no longer part of the cluster. The error looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Address SRI-PC-4630 is no longer in the cluster
    at org.infinispan.affinity.KeyAffinityServiceImpl.getKeyForAddress(KeyAffinityServiceImpl.java:107)
    at org.infinispan.affinity.KeyAffinityServiceImpl.getCollocatedKey(KeyAffinityServiceImpl.java:91)
    at SimpleCache.start(SimpleCache.java:77)
    at SimpleCache.main(SimpleCache.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Where "Address SRI-PC-4630" would be the address of the manager in another JVM that is running. I have been looking online for a solution to this issue but no one seems to have a similar problem.

**2.**
If I do get it running and do a "book" and have a key/value stored in the local node, I cannot access it from any other node.

I have been trying to fix this but to no avail and any advice or recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, I think the problem in 1) is a a bug. Looks like there might be a race condition between getting the address for the given key and then trying to find a new key for that address. If the address is gone, we should be able to re-lookup the address for the given key internally and avoid you have to implement it. Can you create an issue in http://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN?

Comment: For 2) I'm not sure. Can you maybe enable TRACE logging, inspect the logs and see what's up? Even better, if you can come up with a unit test like the ones in https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/tree/master/core/src/test/java/org/infinispan/distribution, it might help resolution :)